# After declaring woocommerce theme support products are no longer displayed

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

The title basically says it all. I'm piecing through publishing my first theme and have copied the woocommerce template files right from the plugin. So they should be identical with no current changes. However, when I add theme support in functions.php I no longer have products displayed. The declaration is basically right from their github:

```
    function bad_billy_beards_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', array(
        'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
        'single_image_width'    => 300,

        'product_grid'          => array(
            'default_rows'    => 3,
            'min_rows'        => 2,
            'max_rows'        => 8,
            'default_columns' => 4,
            'min_columns'     => 2,
            'max_columns'     => 5,
        ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bad_billy_beards_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you need to remove all the files you're not overriding. When you build a theme for WC you add theme support and then only copy templates you're going to override - not all the WC templates.

Comment: I plan to, since (I think) I only want to modify archive-product but, that doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

See this post for [WooCommerce templating mechanism](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304776/how-to-override-woocommerce-specific-loop-or-archive-product-php/304804#304804). One basic principle is: only overwrite things that you want to customize, not more.

So you should remove all files that are not changed, look out for double lines of code(meaning you maybe declare the same things twice, maybe with different vars/namespace and/or something else), which might be the cause why it breaks.

For a custom product layout, I'd simply overwrite ***archive-products.php***

**Edit:** You can use add_theme_support without the array at the end. Try that.

```
<?php
   function bad_billy_beards_add_woocommerce_support() {
       add_theme_support( 'woocommerce');
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bad_billy_beards_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Comment: Thanks, I plan to, since (I think) I only want to modify archive-product but, that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I actually tried that first :/ I've been stuck on this since yesterday.

Comment: I went ahead and uploaded it with the declaration commented out if anyone can catch my error. https://drpgraphicdesign.com/wp-theme-bad-billy-beards/

Comment: I have downloaded your .zip file and will have a look at it later this afternoon.

Comment: I have tested your theme: the products are all being displayed. So, your code is correct - maybe try another system to find out it is not working on your local machine. From my point of view - WC products work.  https://imgur.com/a/AGR2wF0

Comment: That's because the declaration is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I kinda figured it out ... It would seem as I'm missing a bit here.

```
function bad_billy_beard_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', array(
        'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
        'single_image_width'    => 300,

        'product_grid'          => array(
            'default_rows'    => 3,
            'min_rows'        => 2,
            'max_rows'        => 8,
            'default_columns' => 4,
            'min_columns'     => 2,
            'max_columns'     => 5,
        ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bad_billy_beard_add_woocommerce_support' );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'bad_billy_beard_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'bad_billy_beard_end', 10);

function bad_billy_beard_start() {
    echo '<section id="main">';
}

function bad_billy_beard_end() {
    echo '</section>';
}
```